# What was Isaac Asimov's first work?

Tags: isaac-asimov, history-of

I am wondering if Isaac Asimov's first work was published. Is it a short story or novel? Why he want to wrote scifi. Is it published in a book or in a magazine or elsewhere? When did he write it? If his first work is available, please provide me with it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After some search I found that he wrote about the story of his first work in a book entitled "[The Early Asimov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Early_Asimov)".

Here are the answers as a quotes from his book.

**Why**

> I began to write when I was very young-eleven, I think. The reasons
> are obscure, I might say it was the result of an unreasoning urge, but
> that would just indicate I could think of no reason. Perhaps it was
> because I was an avid reader in a family that was too poor to afford
> books, even the cheapest, and besides, a family that considered cheap
> books unfit reading. I had to go to the library (my first library card
> was obtained for me by my father when I was six years old) and make do
> with two books per week.

**When**

> It was not until May 29, 1937 (according to a date I once jotted
> down-though that was before I began my diary, so I won’t swear to it),
> that the vague thought occurred to me that I ought to write something
> for professional publication; something that would be paid for!
> Naturally it would have to be a science fiction story, for I had been
> an avid science fiction fan since 1929 and I recognized no other form
> of literature as in any way worthy of my efforts.

**Title and Idea:**

> The story I began to compose for the purpose, the first story I ever
> wrote with a view to becoming a “writer,” was entitled “Cosmic
> Corkscrew.” In it I viewed time as a helix (that is, something like a
> bedspring). Someone could cut across from one turn directly to the
> next, thus moving into the future by some exact interval but being
> incapable of traveling one day less into the future. My protagonist
> made the cut across time and found the Earth deserted. All animal life
> was gone; yet there was every sign that life had existed until very
> shortly before- and no indication at all of what had brought about the
> disappearance. It was told in the first person from a lunatic asylum,
> because the narrator had, of course, been placed in a madhouse after
> he returned and tried to tell his tale.

**Did he complete it?**

> I wrote only a few pages in 1937, then lost interest. The mere fact
> that I had publication in mind must have paralyzed me. As long as
> something I wrote was intended for my own eyes only, I could be
> carefree enough. The thought of possible other readers weighed down
> heavily upon my every word. -So I abandoned it.
>
> Then, in May 1938, the most important magazine in the field.
> Astounding Science Fiction, changed its publication schedule from the
> third Wednesday of the month to the fourth Friday. When the June issue
> did not arrive on its accustomed day, I went into a decline.
>
> By May 17, I could stand it no more and took the subway to 79 Seventh Avenue,
> where the publishing house. Street & Smith Publications, Inc., was
> then located. There, an official of the firm informed me of the
> changed schedule, and on May 19, the June issue arrived. The near brush with
> doom, and the ecstatic relief that followed, reactivated my desire to write
> and publish. I returned to “Cosmic Corkscrew” and by June 19 it was
> finished. The next question was what to do with it.

**What he did with it...**

**Meeting the editor of Astounding Science Fiction**

> Trying to mask panic, I asked to see the editor. The girl behind the
> desk (I can see the scene in my mind’s eye right now exactly as it
> was) spoke briefly on the phone and said, “Mr. Campbell will see you.”
> She directed me through a large, loftlike room filled with huge rolls
> of paper and enormous piles of magazines and permeated with the
> heavenly smell of pulp (a smell that, to this day, will recall my
> youth in aching detail and reduce me to tears of nostalgia). And
> there, in a small room on the other side, was Mr. Campbell.
> We talked for over an hour that first time. He showed me forthcoming
> issues of the magazine (actual future issues in the cellulose-flesh).
> I found he had printed a ‘fan letter of mine in the issue about to be
> published, and another in the next-so he knew the genuineness of my
> interest.
> He promised also that in case of rejection he would tell me what was
> wrong with it so I could improve. He lived up to every promise. Two
> days later.

**Feedback**

> On June 23, I heard from him. It was a rejection. (Since this book deals with real
> events and is not a fantasy- you can’t be surprised that my first
> story was instantly rejected.) Here is what I said in my diary about
> the rejection: “At 9:30 I received back ‘Cosmic Corkscrew’ with a
> polite letter of rejection. He didn’t like the slow beginning, the
> suicide at the end.” Campbell also didn’t like the first-person
> narration and the stiff dialog, and further pointed out that the
> length (nine thousand words) was inconvenient-too long for a short
> story, too short for a novelette. Magazines had to be put together
> like jigsaw puzzles, you see, and certain lengths for individual
> stories were more convenient than others.

**What happened to it**

> What happened to “Cosmic Corkscrew” after that I don’t really know. I
> abandoned it and never submitted it anywhere else. I didn’t actually
> tear it up and throw it away; it simply languished in some desk drawer
> until eventually I lost track of it. In any case, it no longer exists.
> This seems to be one of the main sources of discomfort among the
> archivists-they seem to think the first story I ever wrote for
> publication, however bad it might have been, was an important
> document. All I can say, fellows, is that I’m sorry but there was no
> way of my telling in 1938 that my first try might have historic
> interest someday. I may be a monster of vanity and arrogance, but I’m
> not that much a monster of vanity and arrogance.

Comment: Damn, I wish he'd kept it! I'd have loved to read it. The time jumping in discrete leaps is neat.

Answer (score 11):

The first story Asimov sold was "[Marooned Off Vesta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marooned_Off_Vesta)," published in the March 1939 issue of the magazine *Amazing Stories*. You can find it in any of [these](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60991)
anthologies.

Answer (score 8):

**1931: First written work – *The Greenville Chums at College***

Asimov's very first work, albeit unfinished, is *The Greenville Chums at College*, a novel which he started in 1931 (at the age of eleven!) He abandoned it after eight chapters. More information can be found in his autobiography, [*In Memory Yet Green*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?103248).

**1934: First published work – *Little Brothers***

Asimov's first published work is [*Little Brothers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93571), an essay that appeared in 1934 in his high school literary magazine. It was republished in [*Before the Golden Age*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?36297) and [*Opus 200*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?39451).

**1938: First short story – *Cosmic Corkscrew***

The first *short story* Asimov wrote for publication is *Cosmic Corkscrew*, which he finished in June 1938. However it was never published and is now lost. For more information see Islam Wazery's answer.

**1939: First published short story – *Marooned off Vesta***

The first published short story by Asimov (and also the first short story he sold) is [*Marooned off Vesta*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60991), as mentioned by Micah. It was completed in July 1938, sold in October (to *Amazing Stories* for $64), and reached the newsstands in January 1939 (the cover date was March).

**1950: First published novel – *Pebble in the Sky***

Asimov's first published *novel* is [*Pebble in the Sky*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1406). It was originally written in 1947 (then called *Grow Old Along with Me*). Asimov revised the novel in 1949, and it was published in January 1950.

Comment: It's worth remembering that *Foundation* had been written and published in magazine form before *Pebble in the Sky*.

Comment: That's right, but many (including myself) consider _Foundation_, _Foundation and Empire_ and _Second Foundation_ to be collections, not novels.